# How to find deepest element from a HTML tree with a certain class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a menu. When a tree is opened, it gets the class `active`. I wan't to get the deepest sub-menu of the menu with the class `active`.

Comment: I don't think that duplicate fits. That question is looking for the deepest child, this question is looking for the deepest child with a specific class.

Comment: Yep. Not a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And a vanilla version :

```
function deepest (subMenu, select) { 
  return [].slice.call (subMenu.querySelectorAll (select)).reduce (
    function (deepest, el) {
      for (var d = 0, e = el; e !== subMenu; d++, e = e.parentNode);
      return d > deepest.d ? {d: d, el: el} : deepest;
    }, {d: 0, el: subMenu}).el;
 };
```

call with

```
deepest (subMenu, '.active');
```

where the second parameter selects the elements to be considered.

Tested on a modified version of [@Rory's fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/32ZXP/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `parents()` collection to count the depth of the element and then return the lowest for the specific selector. Try this:

```
<div>
    1
    <div class="active">1.1</div>
    <div class="active">
        1.2
        <div class="active">
            1.2.1
            <div class="active">1.2.1.1</div>            
        </div>
        <div class="active">1.2.2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="active">1.3</div>
    <div class="active">
        1.4
        <div class="active">1.4.1</div>
        <div class="active">1.4.2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="active">1.5</div>
</div>
```

```js
var $elems = $('.active'), $deepest, lowestLevel = 0;
$elems.each(function() {
    var depth = $(this).parents().length;
    if (depth > lowestLevel) {
        $deepest = $(this);
        lowestLevel = depth;
    }
});
$deepest.css('border', '1px solid #C00');
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/WfrZf/3/)

Comment: I thank you, this is exactly what I wanted to do! One question, how do those comma separated variables work in $elems? I haven't seen anything defined like that before.

Comment: @Sergo It's just defining three different variables. I could have instead written it as: `var $elems = $('.active'); var $deepest; var lowestLevel = 0;`